# VS Code does not respond to input from xdotool

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm sending keystrokes from a terminal to VS Code using [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html), but VS Code does not respond to them. I am successful in sending the same keystrokes to other applications using xdotool, just not VS Code.

Here is an example of what I am executing on the terminal (62918258 is the windowid of the application I'm sending the keystroke 'F8' to):
**xdotool key --window 62918258 F8**

> xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input
>   and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using
>   X11’s XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.

Any ideas how I can get xdotool to work with VS Code? Otherwise, could you suggest an alternative way of programatically sending keystrokes to VS Code?

Answer (score 2):

VSCode is using Electron as UI framework, I suggest you ask this question on their [repository page](https://github.com/atom/electron).